# Postgres with Sequelize takes too long to fetch even a few records from the table

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Postgres with Sequelize in Node.js as backend. The data table has only 242 records but a simple findAll() query takes 5 seconds to fetch 242 results. Ideally it shouldn't take so much time to fetch so little data.

[Postgres table snapshot that displays the total records available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDJKf.png)

Above you can see the total records in a table named "country_data". Similarly, here is the query that I'm using to fetch these records:

```js
const countryDataList = await CountryData.findAll({
   attributes: ['id', 'name', 'dial_code'],
});
```

Here's a snapshot of the total time it took (~8 seconds) when I hit the API endpoint using postman:
[Postman result snapshot to show the total time it took to execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOVUr.png)

What am I doing wrong exactly?

I thought that it must be something related to data bloating, so I ran

`vacuum full country_data;`

which took 28 seconds to execute but the time wasn't minimized for data fetching.

Similarly, I read lots of forums and blogs to find something that would cater to my problem but none of it was remotely close to the issue I've been facing.

Some guidance would be much appreciated, since it is making the overall project unnecessarily slow; the application seems too slow for a production level project.

Comment: People aren't going to click on random links in your post to maybe see an image of some text. You'll want to put the actual text into your question. You don't say if the times are different running the same query via psql or whether you see issues with all your queries. Reading loads of blogs and forums ought to have given you some idea of what people will need if they are to help.

Comment: Did you try to execute the same query in a cycle (for instance, 10 times in a row)? Could you check one cycle time simply using `console.time`/`console.timeEnd`?

Comment: @Anatoly

I'm using the logging feature that is inside Sequelize initialization function. It gives me the time of execution for each query. So yes, I did it many times (12-13 times at least) and the time varied between 3-5 seconds.

Comment: @RichardHuxton posted it for more clarity.

Comment: And how much time does it take to get the same 242 recods in something like PGAdmin?

Comment: Did you check using the local DB?